# Css, keep rotate position after animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

Im having an issue with the next animation, I want toggle classes and make animation with arrow icon to rotate down and when you click again rotate to top, the problem is rotate to top starts from the original position, and I need to keep rotate position:

```js
var contArrow = 0;
$(document).on("click", "button.btnSort", function () {
    if(contArrow==0){
        $(this).children("i.fa-arrow-up").removeClass("rotateTop").addClass("rotateDown")
        contArrow++
    }
    else{
        $(this).children("i.fa-arrow-up").removeClass("rotateDown").addClass("rotateTop")
        contArrow--
    }
    console.log($("i").attr("class"))
})
```

```css
.rotateDown{
    animation: arrowAnimDown 2s linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes arrowAnimDown {
    from{}
    to{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-180deg);
        transform: rotate(-180deg);
    }
}
.rotateTop{
    animation: arrowAnimTop 2s linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes arrowAnimTop {
    from{}
    to{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light btnSort">
    Click 
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: if I dont miss understand, you need to remove : animation-fill-mode: forwards; ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the initial position in your second animation, because when your second animation triggers, it will assume that the element is transformed at `0` and will animate it to `180deg`, so specify it under the `from` of `arrowAnimTop`

```js
var contArrow = 0;
$(document).on("click", "button.btnSort", function () {
    if(contArrow==0){
        $(this).children("i.fa-arrow-up").removeClass("rotateTop").addClass("rotateDown")
        contArrow++
    }
    else{
        $(this).children("i.fa-arrow-up").removeClass("rotateDown").addClass("rotateTop")
        contArrow--
    }
    console.log($("i").attr("class"))
})
```

```css
.rotateDown {
    animation: arrowAnimDown 2s linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes arrowAnimDown {
    from {}
    to {
        transform: rotate(-180deg);
    }
}
.rotateTop {
    animation: arrowAnimTop 2s linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes arrowAnimTop {
    from {
      transform: rotate(-180deg);
    }
    to {
      transform: rotate(0); /* read ahead for alternate animation */
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light btnSort">
    Click 
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
</button>
```

Alternate animation, you can pull it to `-360deg`

```
@keyframes arrowAnimTop {
    from {
      transform: rotate(-180deg);
    }
    to {
      transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add some start positions to arrowAnimTop's from {} values, and set its to {} values to go back to zero:

```
.rotateDown{
    animation: arrowAnimDown 2s linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes arrowAnimDown {
    from{}
    to{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-180deg);
        transform: rotate(-180deg);
    }
}
.rotateTop{
    animation: arrowAnimTop 2s linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes arrowAnimTop {
    from{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-180deg);
        transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
    to{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dZKzpq).